# Show Image stored in byte array form in java servlet

Tags: java, image, servlets

I have image stored as a `byte[]`. Now I want to display it from a Java servlet. I am using this code:

```
response.setContentType("image/gif");
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
out.write(img); // image is of byte[] type.
out.flush();
out.close();
```

But I am getting the error "The image cannot be displayed because it contains an error."

Comment: How have you validated that your byte array is valid? Have you tried fetching the URL using curl, and checking the results against the original data?

Comment: It is correct. Actually I am storing the image to Hbase from reading it from disk in byte array form. And then reading the data from hbase again in byte array form and displaying it to browser through servlet.

Comment: are you shure that you array actually contains the data for a gif image? Or could it be a JPEG, or PNG? Where do you get the data from?

Comment: Actually it is a jpg image. I have tried response.setContentType("image/jpeg"); also, but getting the same error.

Comment: So have you tried fetching the URL with curl (or wget) as I suggested?

Comment: The contentType **needs to match** the data. Therefore using your hard-coded approach is a bad idea - dynamically read the content-type from the image and set the **correct** contentType. Also add `response.setContentLength(img.length);`. Please show us the the result that is returned from the Servlet.

Comment: Yes. I am getting some long unreadable binary data.@JonSkeet

Comment: @Alexander http://postimg.org/image/5tuhb3hxv/  .  Tried with response.setContentLength(img.length);. getting same error

Comment: @HarshSharma. Can you access the image file itself? Please try to write the byte[] to a file and call `file <file>` and `eog <file>`on it to find out what's wrong with the file. From the URL you showed me (S_140x110_...) I suppose that you are doing some image transformation - are you sure that this code is working correctly?

Comment: @Alexander, After transformation I am able to access the image.What I am actually doing is convert the image into byte [] and storing the byte [] into hbase. And when the request is coming for that image I am getting the byte array from hbase and serving the image. The code to convert the image into byte array is http://pastebin.com/68Qfw0g9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the reason was totally different for this error.I am performing my task in two steps =>

First to convert image into `byte[]` and storing into hbase.
And then getting the `byte[]` from hbase and showing it through browser.

In the question I mentioned the code of 2nd part, but the actual problem that was causing the error was in 1st part. The reason of the error was:

Initially I was converting the image into `byte[]` using the code

```
    File imgPath = new File(ImageName);
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(imgPath);

    // get DataBufferBytes from Raster
    WritableRaster raster = bufferedImage.getRaster();
    DataBufferByte data = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();

    return (data.getData());
```

Which was causing the error

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromRenderedImage(ImageTypeSpecifier.java:925)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.getWriter(ImageIO.java:1591)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(ImageIO.java:1520)
    at com.medianet.hello.HbaseUtil.main(HbaseUtil.java:138)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
"
```

When I changed the code to

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    BufferedImage img=ImageIO.read(new File(ImageName));
    ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", baos);
    baos.flush();

    return baos.toByteArray();
```

It worked.